# Extra column is adding on db table in hibernate jpa OneToOne relation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have Three entity class on OneToOne Relation `Product`->`SkuImpl`->`SkuAvailabilityImpl` I just need to add a product, so records are inserting into `sku` table simultaneously into `SkuAvailability` table

*SkuImpl.java*

```
@Entity 
public class SkuImpl implements  Sku {
    @OneToOne(targetEntity=SkuAvailabilityImpl.class, cascade={cascadeType.ALL},fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
    @Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    protected SkuAvailability totalSku;
    //setter and getters
}
```

*SkuAvailabilityImpl.java*

```
@Entity 
public class SkuAvailabilityImpl implements SkuAvailability{
    @OneToOne(optional=true,targetEntity=SkuImpl.class) 
    @Cascade(value={org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="SKU_ID", referencedColumnName='SKU_ID',insertable=false,updatable=false)
    @Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    protected Sku sku;
    //setter and getters
}
```

sku database table is

```
SKU_ID  | NAME   | QUANTITY | SKU_AVAILABILITY_ID 
--------+--------+----------+--------------------
        |        |          |
```

All records are inserting fine, but the problem here is, an extra column is adding on the above table with the name `totalSku_SKU_AVAILABILITY_ID` like below

```
SKU_ID  | NAME   | QUANTITY | SKU_AVAILABILITY_ID |totalSku_SKU_AVAILABILITY_ID
--------+--------+----------+--------------------
101     |product1|  200     |                    |  503
```

I tried deleting that column, but it is creating again. I am not understanding why this column is adding can anyone help me how to stop this?

Comment: You haven't defined the column name for field "SkuImpl.totalSku" so it defines its own column name. @JoinColumn

Comment: @Neil Stockton, thank you very much `@JoinColumn` solved my issue,

Comment: glad to hear it. added as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the column name for field "SkuImpl.totalSku" so it defines its own column name according to JPA spec definitions. 
Add `@JoinColumn` with the name you have in your database.